# Parse Push error "Cannot use GCM for push..." - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am attempting to set up push notifications for my application. I have followed the appropriate quickstart guide and the tutorial and have, as far as I can tell, set everything up correctly, but when I run the app I get the following LogCat error:

```
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775):   <intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775):     <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775):   </intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(17775): </receiver>
```

Here's the relevant excerpt from my manifest:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
        
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    
    <permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      
    <!-- activities excluded to be concise -->
        
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
     <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
         android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
             <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <receiver android:name="com.parse.parsePushBroadcastReceiver"
         android:exported="false" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
             <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <meta-data
         android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
         android:resource="@drawable/push_icon" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've double and triple checked and it seems like I have everything that the error is saying I need. Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Other possibly relevant information:

My launcher activity

```js
public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  Parse.initialize(this, "REDACTED", "REDACTED");
  
  ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("");
  
  ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
  Intent i;
  if (user == null) {
   i = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);
  } else {
   i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  }
  startActivity(i);
  finish();
 }
}
```

There is not currently anything related to pushes in any of my other classes. One possibility I haven't tested yet is that my lack of a ParsePushBroadcastReceiver subclass is causing a problem, but based on the documentation in the Parse API, this doesn't seem to be necessary for the basic push service.

My full manifest, in case it's needed:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 
 <permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LogInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
  <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver android:name="com.parse.parsePushBroadcastReceiver"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
          <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
      android:resource="@drawable/push_icon" />
 </application>
</manifest>
```

I'll happily provide any more information that's requested, this is all I could think of. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp. After all the time I spent on this, it turns out I was just another victim of a typo. Although, I don't actually know what the typo was... I ended up just copy+pasting the error log into my manifest and erasing the timestamp (leaving just the suggested code) and using that to replace the relevant lines. I still can't see a difference, but it's working now. I feel pretty ridiculous.